# How is a port on a shared IP forwarded to my VPS?

Tags: port-forwarding, vps

How does it work on a vps, that i can listen/open ports? if a vps uses the same ip with many others, how get's xx.xx.xx.xx:1234 get translated to my vps and not the others?

Comment: It’s highly unlikely for a commercial VPS not to have an internet-routable IP address assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask

> How does it work on a vps, that i can listen/open ports? if a vps uses
>   the same ip with many others, how get's xx.xx.xx.xx:1234 get
>   translated to my vps and not the others?

I'm no expert - having not used them, but looking at a definition of VPS, I don't think they do use the same IP.  I think xx.xx.xx.xx is your VPS (though perhaps one theoretical exception may be if there is virtual NAT forwarding to a virtual machine, though then you don't really have access to the whole virtual machine, it doesn't seem like a VPS if it's that)

A VPS is a virtual machine you should have full access to. You should be able to install anything on it, and I suppose open any port on it, or close any port on it.

**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server**
A virtual private server (VPS) is a virtual machine sold as a service by an Internet hosting service. A VPS runs its own copy of an operating system, and customers have superuser-level access to that operating system instance, so they can install almost any software that runs on that OS.

--

So if one user has one port and one user has another port then I think that's not a VPS, it's not private if different users/clientelle are accessing different or same ports of the same VPS!  And the VPSs won't be behind NAT either. You could access any port on your VPS and somebody else can access any port on their VPS, you won't access each others and you will access any of your VPSs open ports.

Comment: Well, I contacted one provider of VPS and he told me, that every vps does indeed (in his words: of course) have its own IP. Allthough I believe to having read somewhere that this is no must.

Comment: Allthough I dont really understand, why that all is in the definition of a VPS. Doesn't the virtualization basically mean that there could be any hardware available and unavailable? Having su access and beeing able to uninstall any software doesn't really say anything about the surroundings of the system, or do I get that wrong too?

Comment: @AndiCox what you have asked doesn't quite make sense. you write "any hardware available and unavailable?"  You mean RAM? Printer? I don't know what you mean at all.  Have you ever created a virtual machine yourself? When a virtual machine is made, it is assigned RAM and it has no printer, it has a file that represents a hard disk. it's like a computer so it has all the TCP ports.   You could open a port on it for  ssh or vnc  and onyl let one person access it.   I don't know what you mean by "surroundings of the system".  Outside the virtual machine is another  machine with a different IP .

Comment: So one machine would host many virtual machines each has its own IP,  and each person can use his own virtual machine

Comment: Well, first of all: I don't know what you define as a virtual machine. Having RAM assigned, no printer, and a file as a hard disk (lol) doesn't actually mean anything, that's just true for almost everything. Did I create a virtual machine? I don't know. What do you mean by create? I did run dosbox once, does that count? And now? If a machine runs inside a machine, something from the outside must propagate through the outer machine. Why do you think that a virtual machine can have a network card, but no printer? Does that machine warn me, if I try do print, that it is only virtual? Making the

Comment: machine unvirtual? This is quite a paradox.

Comment: @AndiCox your philosophical questions show a good deep understanding. Also by available/not it wasn't clear whether you meant used/unused vs existent/non-existent.on host or on guest.if it uses the guest it uses the host but is a different perspective.U make an interesting point re what about dosbox.It's an emulator. People seem to struggle to find differences between en emulator and a virtual machine.  I suggest you try virtualbox or vmware, you may find it interesting. You can boot whatever operating system from it. vmware player is free, vmware workstation isn't free. virtualbox is free.

Comment: @AndiCox you could also try a gameboy emulator.. the program is the gameboy and the files it opens are the games, which they call ROMs.  I suppose a gameboy emulator is also emulating a radically different CPU. Vmware or virtualbox is interesting because you choose the OS.  Also many EXE files nowadays are .NET meaning i think there is some kind of virtualization going on prior to converting to native. And all the .NET programming languages c#.net  vb.net  e.t.c. all convert to a .net byte code that is then converted to native. Definitely many funny things going on!

Comment: @AndiCox And re .NET,  MS call it an 'execution environment" which is pretty much their term for virtualization. So all these terms.. "execution environment"  "emulator"  "virtual machine" seem to be used in different and similar situations. There are some SO or superuser questions about what the differences are and sometimes they are kind of untechnical and arbitrary who decides whether something is termed this or that.

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual Service Provider uses network infrastructure for disambiguating the connections like NAT, or even just IPTables. They map incomming ports to servers, and ports on them, so that :1234 is bob's VPS on port 80, and 1235 is Shiela's VPS on port 22, etc. you could do the same thing with most home routers, forwarding a port externally to a machine:port internally, for multiple internal systems.

Additionally, thought this is not your situation, most services can configure a listening IP:port combo, so it is possible to put multiple IP addresses on a box, and have differant sets of services on each one. this may require some NAT/IPTables magic however since no NIC can have port 80 defined twice, one for one IP, and another for another. they would have to put the second service on another port like 81, and use NAT to map external:80 to internal:81. One way to address this would be to install multiple NICs (one per IP) on a system. when correctly configured you can then duplicate port numbers on a per/nic basis. With virtual systems, adding a new virtual nic is trivial, and can be done by script automatically.

There is no way to tell you more about your specific circumstances with the information available.

Comment: What I read about it until now I came to the conclusion, that I had the misconception, that a machine or more accurate a network adapter can only have one single ip address. If that is not the case, then a VPS can run on a machine with several other VPSs and still have it's own ip address. Is that about right? The mapping that you described would require actually to tell the router (or machine, well at least outside the VPS) that you want to have a specific port routed to you. So xx.xx.xx.xx:80 can only be (reasonably) served by exactly one VPS.

Comment: And as listening is passive you cannot just do it von the VPS (if it was indeed a shared ip), as the router is unaware of it.

Comment: if you want to share a single IP address amongst many internal systems, then yes, a gateway of some kind is required. it is quite possible to run multiple IPs on the same nic, but they share a port range, so you can't have two apache instances running on 80, unless you add multiple nics, in which case you can bind one apache service to each of them so you have two port 80 services on two differant IPs. I thought it sounded off that all the shared hosts had the same IP.